# How can I add a list to a list of lists element-wise in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

In the context of creating a metaclass "Shape" with some abstract methods to be overriden by upcoming child classes (like point, line, polygon etc) a concrete "move" method is also to be implemented amongst others. This is used to move all stored coordinate pairs (x/y) according to a specified distance.

Initially, coordinate pairs are provided as tuples and stored in a list of lists, as far as I understood, as specified in the instructions. The distance is a tuple containing a coordinate pair with x and y values. Since coordinate values can consist of one pair of x/y values (point) or n pairs for complex polygons, some flexibility is needed here.

```py
class Shape(object):

   def __init__(self, coords):

        self._coords = list(map(list, coords))

    def move(self, d):

        d = list(d)

        # missing magic
```

Given coordinates are stored as tuple of tuples `xy = ((1,1),(2,2),(3,3))`. After the defined class being initialized with `p = Shape(xy)`, I need `p.move((5,5))` to give the following result:

`p._coords = [[6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8]]`

I already tried sth. like `map(add, p._coords, d)` or `[p+q for p, q in zip(p._coords, d)]` but it didn't work out. I imagine the solution to be a one-liner, but I simply can't wrap my head around.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to stop using python2.7 since it's end-of-life and start using python3.x instead

Comment: Unfortunately I'm bonded to 2.7 since I'm using this mostly in context of ArcGIS for Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this class with `move` as a nested list comprehension:

```
class Shape(object):

    def __init__(self, coords):

        self._coords = coords

    def move(self, d):

        self._coords = [[x + y for x, y in zip(i, d)] for i in self._coords]
```

Testing:

```
xy = ((1,1),(2,2),(3,3))
p = Shape(xy)
p.move((5, 5))
print(p._coords)
```

Output:

```
[[6, 6], [7, 7], [8, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
self._coords = [[(coord + d[i]) for i, coord in enumerate(point)] for point in self._coords]
```

EDIT: Instead of thinking about how to do it in a one-liner, you can always write out the for loop explicitly then convert it to list comprehension form.